# ALT key doesn't seem to work in Firefox

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, firefox

I just plugged in a new replacement keyboard to my 16.04 system. I've got a browser plugin that responds to ALT-` (alt key plus back-quote) to trigger an action. That's worked reliably for years on the other keyboard.

With this new keyboard, which otherwise seems to work just fine, it doesn't work.

With `xev` I can tell that the ALT keys on the keyboard are correctly mapped to `Alt_L` and `Alt_R`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0xd8, subw 0x0, time 426316029, (52,97), root:(1243,556),
    state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

When I'm using anything other than Firefox, I don't get a back-quote character; the system acts as if the ALT key matters. In Firefox, however, hitting ALT+` just gives me a back-quote. If I plug the old keyboard in, it works fine.

What is going on? What is it that I need to do to get Firefox to recognize the ALT key combination?

Answer (score 0):

Durr. My `xmodmap` file lost a directive to set the `mod1` modifier:

```
add mod1 = Alt_L Alt_R
```

Adding that back in made it work. I don't know how it got lost.